# How to fix Makehuman Textures in blender?

Tags: texturing

I imported a model from Makehuman and see whats wrong with the textures and how do i fix it? Remember i have to be in Cycles render. [image]

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to set transparency to "hairy" objects, like lashes and brows.
Though the texture image contains transparent data, in Blender your material is probably set to plain diffuse, which won't read alpha channel generally.
You have to set it manually, combining the diffuse with a transparent shader, and connect the mixing factor with the image's alpha output (see the picture below).

Remember: the image texture must be PNG format. If you have it in JPG for some reason (like you edited and saved it in Photoshop), it won't work.
JPG is only RGB, while PNG is RGBA. That means with Red Green Blue channels comes a fourth one: the Alpha channel, the transparent channel.
(MakeHuman creates PNG textures by default)

In Cyclyes, the shading what you need goes like this:

[image]

Have a nice day! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your material to read alpha of the image as it is filling up all transparency with white color so you just need to add a mix shader with transparent bsdf

Comment: Can you add more details to the answer and screenshots?